# What are the conditions for $n^2 \nmid(n-1)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

> Q: What are the conditions for $n^2 \nmid (n-1)!$, given that $2\le n \le 100$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

According to me the two conditions must be:
1. $n$ is a prime number (since the factorization of $(n-1)!$ will not have a $n$ when n is prime).
2. $n = 2\times$(**prime number**). (Because if $p$ is the prime number such that $n=2p$, then $(2p-1)!$ will have only one $p$ in the prime factorization, but we need two.)

Is there any other condition for $n^2\text{does not divide} ((n-1)!)$ ?

Comment: Just a tip: use `\nmid` ($\nmid$) for "does not divide" rather than `\not |` ($\not |$), which looks unclear and confusing.

Comment: Is there a typos in the post? You wrote $2\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Just a question, why the restrictions? And why $2\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $n=8$ doesn't fit into either 1 or 2

Comment: @user117757 It is actually $n\in \mathbb{N}$...Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the numbers of the form $2^k$ for $k > 1$ have that property?

Comment: @user117757 That works only for $ 1 \le k\le 3 $.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh yes. If we count the number of $n$ that satisfy the question, then we will have $41$ of those, if we follow my conditions and your $8$...However the number of such $n$'s is something else...

Comment: Seems a fairly easy program to type out those $n,$ up to some bound, for which $n^2$ does not divide $(n-1)!,$ and after each such $n$ factor it. Should show you the right way pretty quickly. Then you see whether you can corr3ectly describe the pattern and prove it.

Comment: @WillJagy I think both of my conditions must be true...I think there could be some values of $n$, for which no condition can be formed. One such value is $n=8$.

Comment: shaurya, there is an easy way for you to find out.

Comment: @WillJagy And what is that??

Comment: You can easily find some condition if $n=p^k$ for some prime $p$, or if $n=pq$ for distinct primes $p,q$. The first condition will add $8$ and $9$ to your previous list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $n$ has (at least) two distinct prime factors -- say $p$ and $q$ -- then notice that the factors $\frac{n}{p}$, $\frac{n}{q}$, $p$, and $q$ multiply to get $n^2$.  So we would like to write
$$
n^2 = \frac{n}{p} \cdot \frac{n}{q} \cdot p \cdot q \; \mid \; (n-1)!
$$
(since $p,q, \frac{n}{p}, \frac{n}{q} < n$ are contained in the expansion of $(n-1)!$.)
But a few things could go wrong:

1. $n$ does not have at least two distinct prime factors.  Then either $n$ is a power of a prime, or $n = 1$.  If $n = 1$, in fact $n^2$ does divide $(n-1)! = 1$.  Otherwise, let $n = p^k$, $k > 0$.

   1a. If $k = 1$, then this is one exception (which you list): $\boxed{n \text{ is prime}}$.

   1b. If $p^{k-1} > 2k$, then we can write
   $$
   n^2 = p^{2k} \; \mid \; p^{p^{k-1} - 1} \; \mid \; (p)(2p)(3p)\cdots ((p^{k-1} - 1)p) \; \mid \; (n-1)!
   $$
   1c. Either (1a) or (1b) applies unless $(p,k) = (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,2)$.  These correspond to $n = 4, 8, 16, 9$, of which $\boxed{n = 4, 8, 9}$ are genuine exceptions.
2. $\frac{n}{p}$ could equal $p$ (or $\frac{n}{q}$ could equal $q$).  In this case, $n = p^2$, which is not divisible by $q$ (so this case never happens).
3. $\frac{n}{p}$ could equal $q$ (or $\frac{n}{q}$ could equal $p$).  In this case, $n = pq$.  If $p,q > 2$, then we write
   $$
   n^2 = p^2q^2 \; \mid \; p \cdot q \cdot 2p \cdot 2q \; \mid \; (n-1)!
   $$
   because $p,q, 2p, 2q < pq = n$.  Otherwise, we have the exception $\boxed{n \text{ is 2 times a prime}}$.  (This exception also encompasses $n = 4$ from case 1.)

So: besides $n = 8,9$, your two conditions are correct (and you don't need the restriction $2 \le n \le 100$).

Comment: You don't need $n=4$ as an exception. It is 2 times a prime!

Comment: @shauryagupta Good point.

Comment: What if we were to count the number of values of n that satisfy the restriction $2\le n \le 100$?

Comment: http://ideone.com/zfsd3o says you are right :) (I just coded this in an old Xperia, I am feeling extremely badass for getting it right the first time)

Comment: @chubakueno So are there 42 such values of $n$??

Comment: @shauryagupta There are 25 primes less than 100, and 15 less than 50 (these we multiply by two), so with 8 and 9 also there are 25 + 15 + 2 = 42 such values of $n$.

Comment: What about n having 3 distinct prime factors?

Comment: @shauryagupta When I said "has 2 distinct prime factors" I meant *at least* 2.  Edited now, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Goos But now it could be possible that $\frac np \not = p \text{ or } q$...

Comment: @shauryagupta If $p,q,n/p,n/q$ are four distinct numbers then go back and reread the very beginning of Goos' answer.